# React v16 App Crashes with Reactv18.2 Dependency: Solutions Needed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend

I have a Microfrontend application, where the Parent/Container application is responsible for running all the shared packages, including react and react-dom.

The Parent application is currently running on React version 16.14.0. However, a particular npm package that the Microfrontend app needs to use requires React version 18.2.0. The application is bundled and hosted using Webpack.

Unfortunately, whenever the Microfrontend app loads a component that uses the npm package running on React version 18.2.0, the application crashes. On the other hand, the Microfrontend application runs without any issues when the npm package is not imported. Nonetheless, it is mandatory for me to use the npm package, and hence, I have tried a few solutions to resolve the issue.

1. I attempted to upgrade the Parent container application to React Version 18.2.0. However, this approach failed as there are several dependent modules tied to Version 16.14.0, and also, the application is currently in production.
2. I considered using the 'resolve alias' feature in Webpack to run two different versions of React.
3. I explored Webpack module federation but looks like the npm package owner needs to make changes on their end to expose config which can be used as a remote in the Micro Frontend app.

Is there any other way that I could implement to run the application with two different versions of React?